# How to get the value of an index in hive flutter?

Tags: database, flutter, indexing, dynamic, flutter-hive

I have created a dynamic database using hive in flutter. How can I get the value in a certain index? I need to get the value of `totalSec` in the index . I'm going to delete so I can subtract it's total time but I don't know how.

Here is a sample of my code snippet below:

```
child: new InkWell(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(1000.0),
  onTap: () {
    newRoutineList.removeAt(index);
    rtnConfigBox.deleteAt(index);
    _rtnTotalSec = _rtnTotalSec - rtnConfigBox.getAt(index.totalSec); //Error: the getter 'totalSec' isn't defined for the class 'int'.
    setState(() {});
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

your implementation seems to be correct. However `index.totalSec` needs to be an `int` value.

The Hive documentation contains everything you need to know about using the package

https://docs.hivedb.dev/#/basics/read_write